# Dismiss imagePicker when button is inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to dismiss the view. I have been able to add a target to the button which brings up an action sheet that let's user choose their photo from the library. However after I "choose" an image the view doesn't get dismissed.

Here is what's inside my the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    var  chosenImage = UIImage()
    chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    profileImageView.image = chosenImage


    // This doesn't work...
    self.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("Should dismiss")
}
```

I present the alertController like this:

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Before calling - self.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) ---  try printing self.window?.rootViewController? to be sure nothing is messed up in rootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting and dismissing the UIImagePickerController correctly. The issue must be with how you are presenting it and which view controller is on the top of the stack when you dismiss it. Try presenting it on the current ViewController that contains the delegate.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the delegate is called inside the UITableViewCell

Comment: Try and make your UITableViewController be the one who handles the presenting and the dismissing of the UIImagePickerViewController through delegation.